# Possible to link classic asp and asp.net?

Tags: asp-classic

I am writing to seek advice on the following subject below as I am currently new into web development field:

I have a current website on a classic asp platform and would like to move one of the webpage to asp.net platform. for example: the data.asp would link to webpage datasearch.aspx.

*Is it possible to execute such a link?*

I have a done little research and found you can use ASP to dynamically set URL of the “IFrame” on the server side. *Is this method appropriate for this scenario?*

Comment: It's not clear what you ask. What you mean "link to a web page"? You mean the .asp page should redirect to the .aspx page? Should it send a request and interact with it? Please give more details.

Comment: You could redirect to that page too using `Response.Redirect "datasearch.aspx"`.

Comment: If you want to "move it" your asp.net platform will run classic ASP natively without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of web technology is you can mix and match, so if you want to for example display a form using classic asp and then have the form submit to .net, its fine to do so.

Once a page reaches a client, the language used to generate it is most or less irrelevant.